# Pop random set member from list in Redis

Tags: ruby, redis

I am looking for a way to randomly pop a a Set member from a Set in Redis, but only pop ones that match a supplied list/array.

So for example, I can create (using the Redis gem) a set like so

```
require 'redis'
redis = Redis.new

redis.hmset("user_1", :username, "user1", :password, "password")
redis.hmset("user_2", :username, "user2", :password, "password")
redis.hmset("user_3", :username, "user3", :password, "password")
redis.hmset("user_4", :username, "user4", :password, "password")
redis.hmset("user_5", :username, "user5", :password, "password")
redis.hmset("user_6", :username, "user6", :password, "password")    

redis.sadd("users", ["user_1", "user_2", "user_3", "user_4", "user_5", "user_6"])
```

So at this point I have a set called "users". To get a random user from the set I can do this:

```
@redis = Redis.new
@randUser = @redis.spop("users")
```

But what I want to do is only select a random user from a predefined list, so out of the whole set I only want to ever select `user_1` or `user_2` but without having to create a new set

The idea behind this is that some users have more privileges than others and for certain tests I use I want to select certain users.

```
@redis = Redis.new
@randUser = @redis.spop("users", ["user_1", "user_2"]) # Incorrect syntax but to give illustration of what i want to achieve
```

Is this at all possible?

### Edit

So thinking about this if I have a check after the user has been popped out of the set and then puts it back in if it isn't what i want, this shouldn't cause to much of a time delay?

So something like

```
def choose_redis_user
  @redis = Redis.new
  @randUser = @redis.spop("users")
  if @randUser.includes? ["user_1", "user_2", "user_3"]
    $user_username = @redis.hget(@randUser, "username")
    $user_password = @redis.hget(@randUser, "password")
  else
    @redis.sadd("users", @randUser)
    # How do i return to top to select another user
  end
end
```

I'm going to test this now but how do i put this in a loop so that if the users don't match do a pop again ?

Comment: Anything's possible, it's all one big trade off at the end of the day. Why are you so against creating a new set that consists only of the viable options?

Comment: So for the majority of tests all users can be used, certain tests require certain permissions, but when I start running tests in parallel if a user exists in two sets there could be a time where two tests choose the same user and that will cause tests to fail as no one user can be logged in at the same time

Comment: I'd use a different set for each suite of tests then, and especially given that this is needed solely for testing. In any case, popping only a specific subset from a Redis Set isn't possible.

Comment: thanks for you comments, glad I now know that selecting a subset from a set isnt possible, any ideas on my edit to the question though? I could just put it all in a loop ?

Comment: The edit is problematic - who says you'll get a valid user on the 2nd attempt? or the 10th? or the 100000th?

Comment: well what if i store each attempt into an array, and once ive found my match put everything back into the set.. at least after each iteration my chances improve :-)

Comment: Yeah, you could do that... but still, in terms of complexity this approach will take O(N) operations where N is your total set size. Furthermore, you'll be doing a lot of back and forth between the server and the client and that will surely be a major performance damper...